# How to find and replace the text in the footer of the word document using open XML SDK?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I tried the below code. It works if it is a normal text and left indent is on. If I have the text with the square brackets, it corrupts the docx, and if I have the text to be center aligned in footer, replacing doesn't work. Please help me. Here is my code.

```
    using (var file = WordprocessingDocument.Open(targetFileName, true))
    {
    string content = null;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(
    file.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.First().GetStream()))
    {
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    Regex expression = new Regex("[name]");
    content = expression.Replace(content,"replacement word");
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(             
    file.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.First().GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
         writer.Write(content);
    }                
       file.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }
```

I want to replace multiple words in the footer like [name] | [email] | [telephone]

Document will be corrupted when the text to be replaced has [] in it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in the above code is that every instance of "n", "a", "m", "e" is being replaced with the entire string "replacement word". The xml headers in the .docx file contain those characters, which are being overwritten and corrupted when the Regex runs the Replace function.

This can be fixed by escaping the [] characters as follows:

Regex expression = new Regex("\\[name\\]");